# HTML: iframe and paragraph on the same line

Tags: html, css, iframe, inline

I want to have an iframe and a paragraph on the same line in a div on my HTML page.
This should create a preview of the page and a description next to it.

```
<div class="element">
    <div class="preview">
        <iframe width="640px" height="360px" src="http://example.com" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.5);-moz-transform-scale(0.5);"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outcome should look like this:
[image: The outcome should look like this]

Comment: what have you tried so far? `flexbox` or `css-grid` can solve it.

Comment: I tried inline-block at various elements and float. I'll try your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `inline`, `inline-block` or `float` for styling purpose unless you stylign an e-mail template!

The appropiate tool in this case would be `flexbox` or `css-grid`. A simple setup such as this can be done easily with `flexbox`.

1. Remove the inline-style from the iframe.
2. apply flexbox to the container: `.element { display: flex; }`
3. apply a width to the `.preview` and `.description` that together equals 100%: `.element > div { width: 50%; }`
4. add `element * { box-sizing-border-box; }` to prevent possible overflow issues caused by `borders` and `margins`.
5. add `position: relative;` to the `.preview`
6. add `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;` to the `iframe` so that the iframe fills the entire containers height and width.

```css
.element {
  display: flex;
}

.element > div {
  width: 50%;
}

.element * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
}

.preview iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* for demonstration purpose only */
.element > div {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div class="preview">
    <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox for that:

```css
.element {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
    <div class="preview">
        <iframe width="640px" height="360px" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h4>Header</h4>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or this way:

```html
<div class="element" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:nowrap">
    <div class="preview">
        <iframe width="640px" height="360px" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="description">

        <h4>Header</h4>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well it works, but it will be unresponsive!

Comment: also dont rollback a working code-snippet! A [repro] validates your answer and show that your answer work and how it behaves.

Comment: I wanted to show two ways of applying the css styles, but you deleted the first approach and combined them!

Comment: because `inline-style` should be avoided at all cost in modern web-development (with exeption of e-mail templates). Adding multiple snippets with the evry same solution adds no extra value but bloats the answer unnecessarily.